# Pythonic way to pass around many arguments

Tags: python, arguments

I'm working on a package that contains subpackages and several modules within each subpackage.
Most of the functions need several arguments (~10) that are initiated in the "main" function. Usually, all the arguments are passed to methods that are called from within a function. What is the best way to pass around these parameters ?

Consider the following scenario:

```
def func(arg1, arg2, ...., argn):
  do something  
  ext_method(arg1, arg3,...argk) # Note: all the arguments are not passed to ext_method
  cleanup
```

PS:  Function nesting can go quite deep (say around 10-12 functions starting from main function). 
I considered two alternatives:

1. Inspect method: Construct a dict of all the arguments in the main function with all the arguments. To call a function: Get its argspec using the method in inspect package, and filter out unnecessary arguments from the "global" arguments dict. It looks something like the below snippet.

   ```
   args = {arg1: obj1, arg2:obj2,...}  
   req_args = dict([(k, v) for k, v in args.items() if k in inspect.getargspec(ext_method).args])
   ```
2. key-value method: `ext_method()` is called using argument key-value pairs

   ```
   ext_method(arg1=val1, arg3=val3,...,argk=valk)
   ```

I find the second method to be ineffective because its not easy to change the signature of `ext_method()` as more features are added to the package. Is method 1 a better alternative ?

Comment: If you have many functions that share state, using a class might be a good solution.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

More, better options:

1. Add `**kwargs` to your functions and *ignore* extra arguments:

   ```
   ex_method(arg1, arg2, **kw)
   ```
2. Pass around an object with all arguments as attributes; a [`namedtuple` class](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) would be ideal here. Each function only uses those attributes it needs.

I'd pick the latter. Stop moving around 10 arguments, start passing around just **one**.

Even better, if all those operations are really coupled to the data those arguments represent, perhaps you should be using a class instead:

```
class SomeConcept(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3, .., argN):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        # ... etc.

    def operation1(self, external_argument):
        # use `self` attributes, return something.
```

instead of all those separate functions.

Comment: To extend on this: if the data are coupled very tightly together, it might be worth to define an own class (or to extend a `namedtuple` class) and have the said functions as methods of this class.

Comment: I'd also use a namedtuple.  Who cares if a few fields aren't used by all methods?  There's an example like this in the book Code Complete, I'm pretty sure.

Answer (score 9):

to pass multiple arguments, use the `*` operator and `**` operator.

```
def foo(*arg, **karg):
    print arg, karg
```

The `*` operator pack all ordered argument in it, and the `**` operator packs all unmatched key argument in it.

For example:

```
def foo(a, *arg):
    return a, arg

foo(1,2,3)
>> (1, [2, 3])
foo(1)
>> (1, [])
```

For key argument it works the same way,

```
def foo(a=1, b=2, **kargs):
    return a, b, kargs

foo(2, c=10, b=23)
>> (2, 23, {'c': 10})
```

Then you can mix them up, those sepcial cases are always at the end of the signature like this:

```
def foo(a, c, d=4, *arg, **karg):
    return a, c, d, arg, karg

foo(1, 2)
>> (1, 2, 4, [], {})

foo(1,2,3)
>> (1, 2, 3, [], {})

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
>> (1, 2, 3, [4, 5], {})

foo(1, 2, h=2, f=3, d=4, j=3)
>> (1, 2, 4, [], {'h': 2, 'f': 3, 'j': 3})

foo(1,2,3,4,5, o=2)
>> (1, 2, 3, [4 ,5], {'o': 2})
```

If you want to pass a dict to a function as argument or a list of argument, you can also use those operators:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = {'c': 1, 'd': 3}

def foo(a, b, *arg, **karg):
    return a, b, arg, karg

foo(*a, **b)
>> (1, 2, [3], {'c': 1, 'd': 3})
```