# How far can/should I take args from argparse into my functions and classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, command-line-arguments, argparse

I write a lot of cli tools in python. Most of my tools have something like this to get arguments:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
                    help='an integer for the accumulator')
parser.add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',
                    const=sum, default=max,
                    help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

I write code that is half data science (we're bioinformaticians). This args bit normally lives in "main.py" then gets passed to some sort of "run experiment" function/method which will often use multiprocessing Pool to break the task apart (by passing off to other functions/classes). So most of the arguments from the command line need to be parsed to the run function then the new process. This architecture is not not up for debate for various reasons.

I'm cognizant of this https://python-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing/style.html

BAD

```
def make_complex(*args):
    x, y = args
    return dict(**locals())
```

GOOD

```
def make_complex(x, y):
    return {'x': x, 'y': y}
```

My tools often have 10-20 parameters stored in args, from argparse. So the question is - should I parse them packaged up as args or unpack them and pass them individually? If I explicitly parse each of them to each function/class that they are intended to end up in it means I end up with a lot of redundant code (at least one function will have a massive parameter list that is identical to args). Conversely, if I just pass args around it goes against the zen...

Comment: Opinion based, but I'd provide explicit arguments for user-level functions at least.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pythonic way to pass around many arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527610/pythonic-way-to-pass-around-many-arguments) → convert `args` to a specific parameter object as soon as possible and pass that around.

Comment: `**locals()`... that is like the worst idea ever :D nice way to break your program during even minor refactorings.

Comment: Thanks @mkrieger1. That gets close to the issue. Is args not already a specific parameter object?

Comment: No, it's very unspecific, from the point of view of a function receiving it, it can contain (or not contain) anything.

Comment: `argparse` is not intended to provide your application with its configuration; it parses command lines. Use the return value of `parse_args` to create your *own* application-specific option object as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my opinion.

`args` is a `Namespace` object, a simple class that holds the values as attributes.  It's easily converted to a `dict` with `vars`.

Internally `argparse` code uses a lot of `foo(*args, **kwargs)`, signature, especially for the `add_argument` method.  This gives a lot of flexibility in what parameters it accepts, but also leaves things open for errors.

In the subcommands section, the `argparse` docs has an example of calling functions with `args.func(args)`.  This allows the different `func` to use different parameters.

Often the `args` contains control parameters, things like `debugging`, `logging`, etc.  They aren't the primary parameters, but auxiliary ones that the function may, or may not, use.  Passing those through several layers with `args` (or a `dict`) can be convenient.

On the other hand if a function might be called from other functions and other user interfaces, it may be a pain to have to create a `Namespace` like object just to pass in parameters.

In short, if the function (or class) is written primarily for use by the CLI, passing the whole `args` can be convenient and reasonable.  But if the function might be used with different CLI, or other interfaces (such as in an imported module), more explicit positional and keyword parameters are better.

If your code is organized around classes, it may be reasonable to accept the `args` namespace, and then assign the desired attributes to instance variables.  The instance doesn't use `args` except during initiation.

Comment: "It's easily converted to a dict with vars." It is important to note, this does not *convert* to a dictionary, it *retrieves the actual namespace dictionary for that object*. If you modify that dictionary, you modify the namespace of the object. i.e., `ns = vars(my_obj); ns["foo"] = 42; print(my_obj.foo)` will print `42`